# ModuleNotFoundError when using Mock

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

I'm fairly new to Python.  I'm working on a small Python project, structured as so:

```
artwork_grabber/
|
|-- artwork_grabber/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- helpers.py
|
|-- tests/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- test_module.py
|
|-- README
```

Both `__init__.py` files are empty of any content.

The `helpers.py` file contains a few functions, one of which is as follows:

```py
from os import path
from tinytag import TinyTag

def create_search_term(file_path_to_song):
    """
    Takes in a file path to a song and returns a phrase that will be used to search for the song's corresponding album artwork.

    :param file_path_to_song:  a file path to an .mp3 or .m4a file.
    :type file_path_to_song: `string`, required.

    :return:  an object of type string that represents the search term to be used when finding album artwork for song file passed into the function.
    :rtype:  `string`.
    """
    if str(path.isfile(file_path_to_song)):
        tag = TinyTag.get(file_path_to_song)
        album = tag.get_album()
        artist = tag.get_artist()
        term = f"{artist} {album} Album Cover"
        return term
    else:
        return False
```

I would like to write a test for `create_search_term()` using the Mock Object Library.  In the `test_module.py` function, I have the following:

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import patch

import unittest
from artwork_grabber.helpers import create_search_term


class UnitTests(TestCase):

    mock_song_info = {
        "album": "A Deeper Understanding",
        "artist": "The War On Drugs"
    }

    # patch where the function is USED, not where it is DEFINED
    @mock.patch('artwork_grabber.helpers.create_search_term', return_value=mock_song_info)
    def test_create_search_term(self, mock_song):
        actual_result = create_search_term(mock_song_info)
        expected_result = "A Deeper Understanding The War On Drugs Album Cover"
        self.assertEqual(actual_result, expected_result,
                         "Expected the search terms to match.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The problem is that when I run `python test_module.py` from the terminal (where `pwd` outputs `/path/to/artwork_grabber/tests`), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_module.py", line 5, in <module>
    from artwork_grabber.artwork_grabber import create_search_term
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'artwork_grabber'
```

Any idea what I might be missing?  I've viewed several tutorials on using Mock, but they haven't seemed to help.

Comment: Not related to the question itself, but just as FYI, it looks like you're mocking the function that you want to test, hence making your unit test useless as you're not going through your real function

Answer (score 1):

As documented in [The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter first searches for a `built-in` module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the variable `sys.path`. `sys.path` is initialized from these locations:
>
> - **The directory containing the input script** (or the current directory when no file is specified).
> - **`PYTHONPATH`** (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - ...

So in your case, the path that python would look for your modules is at `/path/to/artwork_grabber/tests` which obviously doesn't contain any `artwork_grabber/helpers.py` since it only contains an `__init__.py` and `test_module.py`. To satisfy either of the 2 ways above as documented, do either of the following:

1. Go to the parent folder `cd /path/to/artwork_grabber` and then execute the test `python tests/test_module.py`. This will satisfy the 1st above which will include the current path thus including `artwork_grabber/helpers.py` and the subdirectories and files in it.
2. Define it in the variable `export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/artwork_grabber` to satisfy the 2nd above.

Note that as pointed out by @MatiasCicero it wouldn't make sense to mock function-x to return y and assert that function-x returned y, the point of testing is to test source code, not to test the test if it correctly did the mock. Ideally, you should run the actual `create_search_term` and pass it a test file `file_path_to_song`.